# Force RTL layout not working

Tags: screen, stock-android, developer-options

[image]

Even though I checked the box of Force RTL layout it seems it don't work properly and due to this many other problems are occurring in my HTC Desire 826 dual SIM, like , my screen is 1080 but YouTube is not showing option for 1080p quality

---

These are some screenshots of Instagram and my bank's app.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "force RTL" setting in the developer options only makes the locale a right-to-left locale if it wasn't already. That is, if your native language isn't right-to-left, this option makes it draw right-to-left anyway. It allows developers who can't read any right-to-left languages to test that their apps work in a right-to-left language.

**The option can't make apps that don't support RTL support it.** The app author needs to update their app to support RTL, and obviously they're only going to do this if they're going to offer translations to RTL languages. An app that only supports English probably won't be written to support RTL.

As a rule, it's a bad idea to start changing developer settings without understanding what they do. They're hidden behind this screen precisely because they can cause unexpected or undesirable behaviour.

Comment: I m worry about that my app support RTL or not , my phone's text , option drop down menus , app logos , etc get abnormally bigger and they are not going back to their normal size even though i turn off developer option

Comment: That's not what you asked about. Maybe you need to edit your question and describe what the actual problem is.

Comment: "*The option can't make apps that don't support RTL support it.*" for reference, [individual apps can even disable RtL layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43999052/2821954).

Answer (score 0):

Your screen is RTL enabled. The settings app is still LTR but check the status bar and the navigation bar it is RTL and that shouldn't affect the video quality please check any other videos in YouTube.

Comment: Yes i checked all videos, even those videos which i saw in 1080p are showing only 720p as highest quality option. I dont know but many apps' text and logo become so huge that they are going outside of screen.

Comment: Please check anyother developer settings like display size. Can you provide some screenshots about apps which has huge text and logo .

Comment: I posted 2 screenshot below as an answer , u can see... As u can see the 3 dots of top right corner if i touch them the drop down which opens is out of screen and i m unable to select any option from there

Comment: Please edit the question and add it. You shouldn't post it in answer. The phone has been reverted to LTR again.  Check whether have you increased the font size or dispaly size. Because it is LTR and the RTL setting shouldn't affect this.

Comment: I chcked it i havent increase the font size

Comment: My possible solutions will be restart the phone, check for changing dpi settings, restart system UI by force stopping it. Toggle again between LTR and RTL to check whether it restore back to current size. Otherwise take a backup and do a factory reset(If nothing happens). I am sure RTL doesn't have any link to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assist and time but i tried all methods you had suggested